# Double degree in mathematics and computer science for PhD admissions

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, statistics

Long story short, I'm really interested in machine learning research and aim to get into a top CS PhD program. I recently got admitted to the best CS program (5 year bsc+msc) in my country but it is not exactly MIT. My main concerns are the lack of math and reputation. I am therefore considering starting another bachelor's in mathematical statistics in parallel.

Assuming I have the talent, ambition and drive to do it with good GPA and side projects, should I?

**How beneficial would this be from a competence stand point for ML research?**

**How beneficial would this be for CS PhD admissions?**

**Math in CS program:**

Single variable calculus

Multi variable calculus

Algebra and geometry (Linear algebra without proofs)

Discreet mathematics

Modelling and simulation

Numerical methods

Probability and statistics

Logic for computer scientists

**Math in Bsc. Mathematical statistics:**

Single variable calculus

Multi variable calculus

Linear algebra (with proofs)

Linear algebra advanced course

Discreet mathematics

Algebra and combinatorics

Analysis A

Analysis B

Foundations of analysis advanced course

Complex analysis

Abstract Algebra

Mathematical logic

Probability 1

Probability 2

Statistical analysis

Stochastic processes and simulation 1

Stochastic processes and simulation 2

Categorical data analysis

Linear statistical models

Theory of statistical inference

**So what do you all think?**

Answer (score 1):

A PhD is a first and foremost a research degree. Having some research experience will be much better than a whole bunch more bachelor's level classes. Instead of doing a double bachelor's, spend that time doing research during your MS degree. Having a published journal or conference paper will probably go a lot further in an application than a double BS

Comment: What would be better; A double bachelor's with some research experience or a single bachelor's with an exceptional track record of research and side projects related to machine learning?

Comment: In my opinion, the later is far far better (assuming that "exceptional track record" includes published papers)